# The AnglularJS Interval Doesn't Pause if pressed the Interval(Continue btn) twice or more

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a Time with Milliseconds continuously running using the AngularJS Interval Feature. I have created a **Pause** and **Continue** button. WHen the **Pause** button is hit it will trigger the AngularJS's Interval.cancel feature and if i click the **continue** button it will trigger the Interval Feature but the Problem is when i hit the **Continue** button twice or more and then hit the **pause** button it doesn't pause and the milliseconds keeps running but it does pause when the **continue** button is hit once. Below is the Screenshot of the UI. A Help is really Appreciated.

[image]

**AngularJS Code**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $interval) {
  $scope.theTime = new Date();

  $scope.startInterval = function(){
         $scope.flag = $interval(function(){
                        $scope.theTime = new Date();
                    }, 6);
    }

    $scope.stopInterval= function(){
       if($scope.flag)
       $interval.cancel($scope.flag);
    }
   // $scope.startInterval();
});
```

**HTML code**

```
<div class="col-lg-12 text-center" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"   >
<h3 ><b id="thetime"><span id="acttime" ng-mouseover="stopInterval()" ng-mouseleave="startInterval()" >{{theTime| date:'hh:mm:ss sss a'}}</span> <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success Start" ng-click="stopInterval()" style="margin-bottom: 70;"> Pause </button>
 <button class="btn btn-sm btn-info Start" ng-click="startInterval()" style="margin-left: -92;margin-top: 25;"> Continue </button></b></h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this , its working

Make `$scope.flag` is undefined while timer is stop.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $interval) {
  $scope.theTime = new Date();
  $scope.flag = 'undefined';
  $scope.startInterval = function(){
         if($scope.flag == 'undefined'){
         $scope.flag = $interval(function(){
                        $scope.theTime = new Date();
                    }, 6);
           }
    }

    $scope.stopInterval= function(){
       if(!angular.isUndefined($scope.flag)){
       $interval.cancel($scope.flag);
       $scope.flag = 'undefined';
         }
    }
   // $scope.startInterval();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<title>Angularjs</title>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
       <div class="col-lg-12 text-center" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"   >
<h3 ><b id="thetime"><span id="acttime" ng-mouseover="stopInterval()" ng-mouseleave="startInterval()" >{{theTime| date:'hh:mm:ss sss a'}}</span> <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success Start" ng-click="stopInterval()" style="margin-bottom: 70;"> Pause </button>
 <button class="btn btn-sm btn-info Start" ng-click="startInterval()" style="margin-left: -92;margin-top: 25;"> Continue </button></b></h3>
</div>
    </div>
</body>
```